# If strftime() returns incorrect info for the locale, what needs fixing? PHP, or the OS?

Tags: php, internationalization, centos, strftime

It's a minor thing, but it gives me capitalised Portuguese month names when they should be all lowercase.  I can obviously fix it with code, but I'd rather it was right in the first place.  Might there be a patch, or one in the works?  I'm assuming it's an OS thing, rather than a PHP thing?

uname -a gives me

```
2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 22:00:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(CentOS 6.7)

PHP 5.6.15

Comment: I'm afraid it's perfectly normal, converting to lowercase is the developer's job : https://3v4l.org/A3i4T

Comment: Spanish and French correctly come out as lowercase...

Comment: And your link is showing English, correctly capitalised.

Comment: Does `date` on your system in the Portuguese locale show them the way you expect or the way php does?

Comment: That shows the same as php.